# How to Manipulate 2D Array Data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a list of start and stop times for individuals doing tasks over a week.

When they change tasks a new entry is made.

This info is stored in a 2D array. - I want to loop through this Array and store the data in another array.

In the new 2D array I want a row to show a person on a particular day.

So if the first array stores: (Person,Day,In,Out,Total)

```
{{"John","Mon","08:00","12:00","4.00"},
 {"John","Mon","12:00","17:00","5.00"},
 {"John","Tue","08:00","17:00","9.00"},
 {"Mike","Tue","08:00","11:00","3.00"}
 {"Mike","Tue","11:00","17:00","6.00"}};
```

I want the second array to store:

```
    {{"John","Mon","08:00","17:00","9.00"},
     {"John","Tue","08:00","17:00","9.00"},
     {"Mike","Tue","08:00","17:00","9.00"}};
```

Here's my code so far:

```
 public class CompArrayTest {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String[][] End = new String [5][5];
    String[][] Start = {{"John","Mon","08:00","12:00","4.00"},
                        {"John","Mon","12:00","17:00","5.00"},
                        {"John","Tue","08:00","17:00","9.00"},
                        {"Mike","Tue","08:00","11:00","3.00"},
                        {"Mike","Tue","11:00","17:00","6.00"}};



    //print start 
    for(int i = 0; i<Start.length; i++){ 
      for(int j = 0; j<Start.length; j++){
          System.out.print(Start[i][j]+" ");

      }//j end
     System.out.print("\n");
    }//i end

    //change end 
    for(int i = 0; i<Start.length; i++){ 
        String name = Start[i][0];
        String day = Start[i][1];
        String In = Start[i][2];
        String Out = Start[i][3];
        String Total = Start[i][4];

       //look through End
      for(int j = 0; j<5; j++){

      String eN= End[j][0];
      String eD= End[j][1];

      if(eN==name && eD==day){
      //change end time
      End[j][3]=Start[i][3];

      //parse and add times
      double TS = Double.parseDouble(Start[i][4]);
      double TE = Double.parseDouble(End[i][4]);

      double ans = TS + TE;
      String ANS = ans+"";

      End[j][4]= ANS;


      } else {



      End[j][0] = name;
      End[j][1] = day;
      End[j][2] = In;
      End[j][3] = Out;
      End[j][4] = Total;


      }//else end


      }//j end
     System.out.print("\n");
    }//i end

 //print end 
    for(int i = 0; i<Start.length; i++){ 
      for(int j = 0; j<Start.length; j++){
          System.out.print(End[i][j]+" ");

      }//j end 
     System.out.print("\n");
    }//i end

}//main end
```

Comment: An easier way would probably to create a class for an "Employee", say. Have its member variables be the name, time in/out, and the hours worked

Answer (score 0):

1) You could create a class for Employee, but my answer will deal with your style of choosing a 2D array.

2) You shouldn't be allocating a 5 by 5 array for your finished array. The number of columns could be 5, sure, but what if you have duplicates like in your example?

To solve the second issue, I would use a `for` loop and a counter variable to iterate through the identification variable for each person. In this case, I'm going to assume every "Name" is different, so you could just check to see if the Name and the Day are the same, and if so, don't increment the counter. In the end, you have a perfectly sized 2D array.

Next, create an algorithm to count the number of hours worked given the time in and out.

Finally, use another `for` loop, go through and check if the Name and Day are the same. If so, add those hours up and create a new row with that data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use an object Employee which agregate a collection of Session. 
The Object Session :

```
public class Session {
    private String day;
    private String in;
    private String out;
    private String total;

    Session(String day, String in, String out, String total){
        this.setDay(day);
        this.setIn(in);
        this.setOut(out);
        this.setTotal(total);
}
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public String getIn() {
        return in;
    }
    public void setIn(String in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
    public String getOut() {
        return out;
    }
    public void setOut(String out) {
        this.out = out;
    }
    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }   
}
```

And the object Employee :

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private List<Session> sessions;

    Employee(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
    }

    public boolean addSession(String day, String in, String out, String total){
        return sessions.add(new Session(day, in, out, total));
    }
}
```

But a question remains to implement the behavior of employee. What would happen in case of discontinuity for Mike in my exemple below :

```
{{"John","Mon","08:00","12:00","4.00"},
 {"John","Mon","12:00","17:00","5.00"},
 {"John","Tue","08:00","17:00","9.00"},
 {"Mike","Tue","08:00","11:00","3.00"}
 {"Mike","Tue","12:00","17:00","6.00"}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but I managed to figure a solution that solves my issue when looping through the **Start Array**.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Start.length; i++) {
        String name = Start[i][0];
        String day = Start[i][1];
        String In = Start[i][2];
        String Out = Start[i][3];
        String Total = Start[i][4];

        int emptyLine = 0;
        int lastLine = 0;

        //gets first emptyline, lastfilled line
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            if (End[j][0] == null) {
                emptyLine = j;
                if (j > 0) {
                    lastLine = j - 1;

                }
                break;
            }
        }//get Empty

        String eN = End[lastLine][0];
        String eD = End[lastLine][1];

        if (eN == name && eD == day) {
            //change end time
            End[lastLine][3] = Start[i][3];

            //parse and add times
            double TS = Double.parseDouble(Start[i][4]);
            double TE = Double.parseDouble(End[lastLine][4]);

            double ans = TS + TE;
            String ANS = ans + "";

            End[lastLine][4] = ANS;

           // System.out.println("Test If " + name + " " + day + " " + In + " " + Out + " " + Total);

        } else {

            End[emptyLine][0] = name;
            End[emptyLine][1] = day;
            End[emptyLine][2] = In;
            End[emptyLine][3] = Out;
            End[emptyLine][4] = Total;

           // System.out.println("Test Else " + name + " " + day + " " + In + " " + Out + " " + Total);

        }//else end


    }//i end
```

This gives me my desired output. However thanks for the advice on making employee objects, I'll use that in future.

**Start Array**

John Mon 08:00 12:00 4.0
John Mon 12:00 17:00 5.0
John Tue 08:00 17:00 9.0
Mike Tue 08:00 11:00 3.0
Mike Tue 11:00 17:00 6.0

**End Array**

John Mon 08:00 17:00 9.0
John Tue 08:00 17:00 9.0
Mike Tue 08:00 17:00 9.0
null null null null null
null null null null null